# linux + g++: command not found

Tags: linux, g++

I want to install on my Linux red-hat machine `gettext-0.19.1.tar.xz`.

First I do the following

```
cd gettext-0.19.1
./configure
make
```

During `make` it fails on `g++: command not found`

```
libtool: compile:  g++ -DIN_LIBASPRINTF -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -c autosprintf.cc  - o .libs/autosprintf.o
./libtool: line 1128: g++: command not found
make[5]: *** [autosprintf.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gettext-0.19.1/gettext-runtime/libasprintf'
make[4]: *** [all] Error 2
make[4]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gettext-0.19.1/gettext-runtime/libasprintf'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gettext-0.19.1/gettext-runtime'
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gettext-0.19.1/gettext-runtime'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/tmp/gettext-0.19.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How do I fix this?

Remark - I have GCC

```
which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: You are ruining your system. To install new software, you should be using `yum` and existing repositories. **Please stop to read RedHat's own manuals** before entering any more commands as root.

Comment: I wonder if there shouldn't be a canonical question regarding the command not found error.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Install the suite of development tools first. Then go back to compile the software.

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

You could need much more than just the compiler. The Development Tools package includes the core development tools like `automake`, `gcc`, `perl`, `python`, `flex`, `make`, `gdb`, `bison`, and many more. To list all of the software in the package group, use `yum` as follows.

```
yum group info 'Development Tools'
```

For Fedora 20 (at least), you'll additionally need to install `gcc-c++`.

For Debian-based systems, install the suite of development tools as follows.

```
apt-get install build-essential
```

In [Void Linux](https://voidlinux.org/), it's `xbps-install -Su base-devel`, which provides `m4`, `autoconf`, `automake`, `bc`, `binutils`, `bison`, `ed`, `libfl-devel`, `flex`, `libgcc-devel`, `kernel-libc-headers`, `glibc-devel`, `isl`, `cloog`, `mpfr`, `libmpc`, `gcc`, `libstdc++-devel`, `gcc-c++`, `gettext-libs`, `gettext`, `groff`, `libtool`, `make`, `patch`, `pkg-config`, `texinfo`, `unzip`, and `xz`.

Comment: I have perl version - v5.10.1

Comment: download the gcc-c++ but stil the same problem

Comment: now I can use yum , but its fail on  GPG key retrieval failed: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-oracle:

Comment: Then run `yum update`

Comment: On FC20 `sudo yum group install "Development Tools"` fails to install g++. For that you also need `sudo yum install gcc-g++`

Comment: This worked for me on an Amazon Linux EC2 instance, needed g++ to compile the "sharp" node module. Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

On CentOS 7, I only needed

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

(but maybe I already had most of the other development packages)

Comment: worked on RHEL 7.5 too